# Django Model Use Text Choices From Another Model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

In my Django model, I want to use the text choices from another model, but I don't want to use it as a foreign key, because I want the whole list of weekdays before any Day object exists.

If I use it as a foreign key, I will need to create Day object first.

Can anyone help to solve this?

```
class Day(models.Model):
    class Weekdays(models.TextChoices):
        MONDAY = "Monday"
        TUESDAY = "Tuesday"
        WEDNESDAY = "Wednesday"
        THURSDAY = "Thursday"
        FRIDAY = "Friday"
        SATURDAY = "Saturday"
        SUNDAY = "Sunday"

    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=Weekdays.choices)


class School(models.Model):
    
    weekday = ???
```

Comment: What about using `get_or_create` to get or create a `Day` when assigning it to the  `School`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reuse the `Weekdays` from the `Day` model, with:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    # …
    pass


class School(models.Model):
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=Day.Weekdays.choices)
```

Since the choices do not really "belong" to any of the two models, it might make more sense to define these *outside* the two class, so:

```
class Weekdays(models.TextChoices):
    MONDAY = "Monday"
    TUESDAY = "Tuesday"
    WEDNESDAY = "Wednesday"
    THURSDAY = "Thursday"
    FRIDAY = "Friday"
    SATURDAY = "Saturday"
    SUNDAY = "Sunday"


class Day(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=Weekdays.choices)


class School(models.Model):
    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=Weekdays.choices)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! However, I missed out an requirement, I would like `weekday` to be a foreign key in `School`. I used this code `weekday = models.OneToOneField(Day, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=Day.Weekdays.choices)`, and in the admin panel, I am able to see the option for weekdays, but I am unable to save the record because it said the choice is invalid. (because it is supposed to be a Day object?) Do you think it's possible to do that?

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem! Since I need two fields as my primary key, I use the first field (other model) as a foreign key, and use the text choices field as a primary key, and it finally works as intended! Thanks so much again for your help!