# Defining choices outside of model producess fields.E005 error

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Sport(models.IntegerChoices):
    SWIMMING = 0, _("Swimming")
    HIKING = 1, _("Hiking")
    RUNNING = 2, _("Running")

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        help_text="Manufacturer name as displayed on their website",
    )
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    sport = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Sport)

class OrganisationClass(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False)
    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
    )
    sport = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Sport)
```

which produces the `FAIClass.sport: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.` when I run `manage.py check` and I don't understand why. I got the idea to do it based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577998/django-model-use-text-choices-from-another-model), I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: You need to write `choices=Sport.choices` instead of `choices=Sport`

Comment: Oh man I totaly missed it. Thank you!